# imacros javascript loops through csv file

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

I have this code to visit URL and scrape its content, it has a function for searching dynamic frame, all are working fine. Now I want it to loop through a csv file contains URL line by line, how would I do that?

```
var visitUrl;
visitUrl =  "CODE:";
visitUrl += "URL GOTO=http://www.example.com" + "\n";
visitUrl += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";

var getSiteInfo;
getSiteInfo =  "CODE:";
getSiteInfo += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:Title EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
getSiteInfo += "FRAME F={{frame}}" + "\n";
getSiteInfo += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:iframeContent EXTRACT=HTM" + "\n";
getSiteInfo += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=E:\ FILE=File.csv" + "\n";

//////////Beginning/////////////
iimPlay(visitUrl)

//calling for the function which will find the frame
var frame=SearchFrame();

iimSet("frame",frame)

function SearchFrame() {
    var check =  "CODE:";
    check +=  "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
    check +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:iframeContent" + "\n";

    frame=0;

    for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        iimSet("i",i)

        //if the result of the macro is true save frame number and break

        if(iimPlay(check)==true) {
            frame=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //return frame number
    return frame;
}

iimPlay(getSiteInfo)
```

One more question, when I add

```
getSiteInfo += "SET !EXTRACT EVAL(\"var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; text.replace(/<\s*\\/?\s*div\s*.*?>/g, ''); \")" + "\n";
```

I got error: wrong format of SET command, line 6 (Error code: 910), is there anything wrong with this line?

Comment: re when you add a line, maybe the error is something to do with the quotes though I don't know what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSiteInfo += "SET !EXTRACT EVAL(\"var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; text.replace(/<\s*\\/?\s*div\s*.*?>/g, ''); \")" + "\n";
```

Replace this with.

```
var text=iimGetLastExtract();

text=text.replace(/<\s*\\/?\s*div\s*.*?>/g, '');
```

It should solve your problems.